# How to use FilesDir.Path property outside Activity(Xamarin.Android)?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I create the following class:

```
public class GlobalVariables
{
    public static string databasePath = FilesDir.Path;
    private GlobalVariables()
    {
    }
}
```

But FilesDir.Path is underlined with red and it doesn't allow me to import its namespaces to use it. When I use it in some Activity I'm able to but when I'm trying to use it in a class like that I'm not able to. With that class I'm trying to get the apk folder path of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to use FilesDir.Path property outside Activity(Xamarin.Android)?

You need using a [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) to implement this feature:

```
public class GlobalVariables  
{
    public static string databasePath = Android.App.Application.Context.FilesDir.Path;
    ...
}
```

Furthermore, you could refer to: [What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android)